# Blob in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a file downloader in TypeScript using the FileSystem API.

When I'm trying to create a new Blob object:

```
var blob: Blob = new Blob(xhr.response, JSON.stringify(mime));
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

It's possible to create a Blob without any parameters:

```
var blob: Blob = new Blob();
```

But that doesn't help.

The (deprecated) fall back for Blob is the BlobBuilder object but TypeScript (VS 2012 Plugin) only offers the `MSBlobBuilder` object.

What am I doing wrong? Or does TypeScript not know about the Blob constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition for `Blob` in the lib.d.ts library only includes an empty constructor:

```
declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (): Blob;
}
```

If this is incorrect, you could submit back the corrected version, or override it in your code. Here is a rough guess at what the original declaration should look like.

```
declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (): Blob;
    new (request: any, mime: string): Blob;
}
```

I haven't specified the type for the first parameter and the names may be wrong - but as you know what `Blob` is up to, you can adjust these as required.

Comment: I forgot to mention, `lib.d.ts` can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0` on 64 bit machines.