# How do I add Blob to Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, blob

I am attempting to save a file with FileSaver, which consequentially needs a Blob format. My app is being written in typescript.

When I tried to do

```
import * as Blob from "blob";
```

I received the error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'blob'. '/Users/path/to/project/node_modules/blob/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try \npm install @types/blob` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'blob';``
```

I cannot just import 'blob' because a `@types/blob` package does not exist.

I created a declaration file `blob.d.ts` with these contents

```js
declare module 'blob' {
  function Blob(blobParts[, options]): any
  export = Blob
}
```

based on the [MDN entry on the Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Constructor)

This did not solve my issue for the one line of code I need Blob for

```js
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

it returned the error below

```
Argument of type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any, any]'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'type' does not exist in type '[any, any]'.
```

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124080/blob-in-typescript) is NOT a duplicate and its answer does not help me since that declaration file does not declare a module and does not export anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), make sure to include [`webworker`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/00bf32ca3967b07e8663d0cd2b3e2bbf572da88b/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L552-L561) in your [`lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) array:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["webworker"],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Even though it should have already been obvious from the reference links provided above, `lib.webworker.d.ts` contains the declarations necessary for `Blob` and related interfaces.

```
interface Blob {
    readonly size: number;
    readonly type: string;
    slice(start?: number, end?: number, contentType?: string): Blob;
}

declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new(blobParts?: BlobPart[], options?: BlobPropertyBag): Blob;
};
```