# Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<typeof import("buffer")>'

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am trying to set a `Blob` value when using `useState(Blob)` it's not working -,-

Tried to use `null` or `String` or just leave it blank, It is the same issue.

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import Blob from 'buffer';

const [uploaded, setUploaded] = useState(false);
const [video, setVideo] = useState(Blob);

const uploadMedia = async () => {
  if (uploaded) return;
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 0,
  });
  if (!result.cancelled) {
    const response = await fetch(result.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    setVideo(blob); /* < Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to 
                    parameter of type 'SetStateAction<typeof import("buffer")>' */
  }
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how dumb was this.

Anyways, I just fixed it.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124080/blob-in-typescript)

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

declare var Blob: {
  prototype: Blob;
  new (): Blob;
  new (request: any, mime: string): Blob;
};

const [video, setVideo] = useState(new Blob());
const [uploaded, setUploaded] = useState(false);

const uploadMedia = async () => {
    if (uploaded) {
      return;
    }
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 0,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      const response = await fetch(result.uri);
      let blob = new Blob();
      blob = await response.blob();
      setVideo(blob);
      setUploaded(true);
    }
  };
```

` ❤